# Operations time durations in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am working on a datasets in Excel in which I have a column named Duration containing values such as 11:01, 01:39:13 etc. The format here is either hh:mm:ss or mm:ss. How can I do operations such as addition & subtraction on such values?
The file is of XLSX format & I am working on the latest version of Office.

Comment: if `11:01` is truly `mm:ss` just subtract one from the other.

Comment: I have formatted the entire Duration column in the "Time" formatting. And then, for example, if I try to add 11:01,  03:47 &  01:39:13 which are in cells B2, B3 & B4 respectively using the formula "=SUM(B2:B4)", I am getting result as 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your "times" are actually text that look like times.  They will need to be converted to actual times to be summed.

The issue is that if one does a straight conversion on `11:01` Excel will assume `hh:mm` not `mm:ss`

So we need to add some parsing to get the correct time format then sum the results:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--RIGHT("00:"&B2:B4,8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott.
How to do the same for individual cells(without using range(:) operator), when the duration values are non-sequential?
Also, how to do subtraction operation on the same?